# how to create an output file based on xml data in mule

Tags: mule

Im very new to mule so hopefully someone out there can help me out. Im trying to create an output based on a content in my xml
Ex

```
<Header>
   <UniqueID>AAA_12345</UniqueID>
</Header>
```

Id like the filename to be the the UniqueID ie AAA_1245.xml

I found a few syntax on the net but it doesnt work for me. My syntax is

```
<file:outbound-endpoint path="${cwMessagesPath}/out" outputPattern="#[xpath:/Header/UniqueID].xml" connector-ref="cwksbDefaultFileConnector" />
```

for some reason, mule creates #[xpath: as a directory, Header as another directory and then the filename as UniqueID].xml

Im using mule 2.2.1

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

Is `cwksbDefaultFileConnector` configured in any specific manner?

Also, I think in Mule 2 it was possible to configure other placeholders than `#[ ]` for expressions. Are expressions working with this syntax elsewhere in your application? If yes, then the problem is different.

Do you run standalone or embedded? If embedded, make sure you have the `mule-module-xml` dependency in your project's POM.

Finally, what is the payload type of the message that hits the `file:outbound-endpoint`? Maybe some manual transformation is needed in Mule 2 before using XPath.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your reply.  I tried using all possible syntax but i guess it;s more of mule version than anything else. Just waiting for the company to upgrade to mule3.  thanks again.